# My C++ Program wont accept inputs after the menu

Tags: c++, iomanip

I am doing a program for a class in school, and when I try to run the code I wrote below (only half of the project is done, but it's in a state where it should run anyways) the menu comes up fine, but then it jumps straight to the end of the program and wont let me input the important part..

When I remove the menu (which will be a necessity later when I finish the project) it works fine, but when it's there like I need it to be, it wont run properly

```
//Project 4 Written By Nate

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int menuOption;
char stockName[21],symbol[10];
float openingPrice,closingPrice,numberShares,gain;

int main()
{
    // MENU //
    cout<<"Welcome to Project 4! Please select the program you would like to run:\n\n 1)Stock Program\n\nEnter your selection: ";
    cin>>menuOption;
    if(menuOption == 1) {
        goto stockProgram;
    } else
    {
        cout<<"Invalid response received. Program will now terminate";
        return 0;
    }

    stockProgram:
    cout<<"This program will ask you information about a stock you own.\n\n";
    cout<<"Enter stock name: ";
    cin.get(stockName,21);
    cin.ignore(80,'\n');
    cout<<"Symbol: ";
    cin.get(symbol,10);
    cin.ignore(80,'\n');
    cout<<"Enter opening price: ";
    cin>>openingPrice;
    cout<<"Enter closing price: ";
    cin>>closingPrice;
    cout<<"Enter the number of shares: ";
    cin>>numberShares;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    gain=(numberShares*closingPrice)-(numberShares*openingPrice);
    cout<<setw(10)<<"Stock Name"<<setw(10)<<"Symbol"<<setw(10)<<"Opening"<<setw(10)<<"Closing"<<setw(10)<<"Shares"<<setw(11)<<"Gain\n";
    cout<<setw(10)<<stockName<<setw(10)<<symbol<<setw(10)<<openingPrice<<setw(10)<<closingPrice<<setw(10)<<numberShares<<setw(10)<<gain<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"=====================================================================\n";
    cout<<"  This gain could've been yours, too bad you are an anti-mac person.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Strongly consider using a function rather than `goto stockProgram;`.

Comment: Recommend testing the input to ensure the read succeeded and the stream is not in a fail state. `if (cin>>menuOption) { do stuff } else { handle error }`

Comment: Has anyone let you in on [Debugging software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)? A debugger comes with just about every development environment worth using. It will allow you to control the execution of your program, running it line by line if need be, and monitor the state of the variables. Knowing how to use debuggers will make your life a lot easier and debugger use is an essential skill for the working programmer.

Comment: `cin>>menuOption;` will leave a newline in the input buffer. You might want to add another `ignore` before the first `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably still have the a newline character or other characters after the 1 in the initial input. You've used cin.ignore on other inputs but not the first.

```
cout<<"Welcome to Project 4! Please select the program you would like to run:\n\n 1)Stock Program\n\nEnter your selection: ";
cin>>menuOption;
cin.ignore(80,'\n');
```

ignore will extract the delimiting \n

Also, whenever dealing with istream check that it was successful in getting the input into the correct type:

```
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

int myVariable;
if( (cin >> myVariable).fail() )
{
    // Error - input was not an integer
    std::cerr << "Input was not an integer" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding [`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) after `cin>>menuOption`- this will read the one `int` that currently resides within the buffer & discard it since the EOF is the new line after input.

```
int main()
{
    // MENU //
    cout<<"Welcome to Project 4! Please select the program you would like to run:\n\n 1)Stock Program\n\nEnter your selection: ";
    cin>>menuOption; cin.ignore();
    if(menuOption != 1) {
        cout<<"Invalid response received. Program will now terminate";
        return 0;
    }
//etc
}
```

Comment: Recommend turning that `cin.ignore();` into `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to make sure you get everything. That or nuke the site from orbit.

Comment: Could you clarify as to why you would override the already correct default parameters?  The stream size is one.  The delimiter is EOF which equates to a new line within this context.

Comment: Input of "10 " and the like. Either trap it as bad input here so the user knows where they screwed up or allow it.